# Cannot log in to minecraft (Loading forever)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

After June 15, I wasnt able to login into my account on minecraft. This is two days after the new Minecraft Launcher came out. It is forever stuck on the login screen.
Ive tried re-installing minecraft and resetting my password. I can however login through the minecraft.net website. I have looked online, and nothing works. I though maybe this was a Minecraft Server issue, but even today I cannot login. Any ideas? If this helps, I am in Canada.

### Possible error causing:

I have JDK 8 64BIT installed on my machine and the environment vars set (which is NOT used for minecraft, maybe minecraft is tring to use them?) I use them for programming.

Comment: Have you re-installed Minecraft? Also might be worthwhile to check if your PC has any pending updates/did any updates on/around June 15

Comment: @Ben Sorry. I made a mistake in my writing. I did not reinsall java, I did reinstall Minecraft. I have JDK 8 installed on my machine (Not use for minecraft, maybe that's the problem?) I will edit the question accordingally

Comment: Are you using Windows 10? There was an update this week, which also may have caused the problem. Try reinstalling Minecraft, or if that doesn't work, try updating or reinstalling your JRE. I have both JDK and JRE and I can do both playing and programming.

Comment: So you are already using the new launcher? It's a beta version, it's likely to contain bugs. If you activate the debug output, what does it say?

Comment: @FabianRöling I had no choice to install it because when I opened the minecraft launcher, it updated.

Comment: Weird, I thought it was a test version. What about the other questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears it was just a bug. Classic minecraft. I recived an update today to minecraft launcher, now everything is fine. If anyone elase is experincing my issues, I would reccomend reinstalling minecraft and updating to the latest version.